# Android NavigationDrawer transparency

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I’ve implemented NavigationDrawer with android-support-v4 as per [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

My result is on this screenshot.

The question is how to remove or configure these transparency on Drawer which looks awful with background text.

[image]

**UPDATE:** 
here is my layout configuration, with background been set to dark

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @almyz125 See my response below in discussion. It was just a stupid mistake with fragment replace transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone who tried to answer my question.
I'm sorry the trouble was in Fragment initialization in code.

So I've tried to add fragment as new instance, but it should be just a replacement of already defined fragment in layout as follows:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FeedFragment fragment = new FeedFragment();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

now everything works fine.

Comment: So your question was not about the Drawer transparency, but 'twas about the fragments overlapping each other

Answer (score 3):

You need to add alpha to your `ListView`.
Use your XML and extend the `ListView` definition with alpha-attribute.

```
<ListView
     android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
     android:layout_width="240dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
     android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
     android:dividerHeight="0dp"
     android:background="#111111"
     android:alpha="255"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this in you code.
Get the background of the drawer view and set alpha for it.

```
  Drawable background = drawerView_.getBackground();
  background.setAlpha(255);
```

Answer (score 1):

To make navigation drawer transparent, you must first define the color for your drawer in res/values/colors.xml file.
Eg:`<color name="navigationDrawerNew">#7ba9530c</color>`

Now, on the left side of this line, the color that you have chosen will be displayed in a small square.

[See image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daYmm.png)

Click on it. It will bring up a color chooser. In the color chooser, at the bottom, there is a slider which allow you to adjust transparency. Adjust it to get the required transparency.
Now, set this color as background color for the list view for navigation drawer in xml file. The list view looks almost like this:-

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navList"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:background="@color/navigationDrawerNew" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the Background of the Drawer (Which in the linked demo is a ListView) to a solid color/drawable

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't default to be transparent like this. You must have it set in your activities layout file. Change the `android:background` in the `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` tag to be a solid colour

Comment: Updated my question with layout, I've already tried to change it.

Comment: It looks to me like the content is somehow on top of your drawer layout, rather than the drawer being transparent. Is the xml you posted the whole file? The `android.support.v4.DrawerLayout` element must be the first thing in your layout file

Comment: DrawerLayout as the first thing in layout file - yes, as per example. Doesn't help here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What's the layout that your `Adapter` inflates in the 
`getView(LayoutInflater inflater, ..., ...)` ?

The ListView inflates some layout and this one seems to be transparent, not the drawer.
The background color of your Drawer becomes the color of ListView's items.

You can notice that the second part of your drawer is a little bit darker then the items.

Comment: I don't use `NavigationDrawerAdapter` at all here - as per example  http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: As you can see, you actually have an Adapter. How you call it is up to you. `mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item/*this is the layout that your ListView inflates*/, mPlanetTitles));`

Just have a look within this layout and check it's background.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to setBackgroundColor for DrawerListView in the code like this:

```
mDrawerListView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
```

This is work for me. No need to add Alpha value.

Answer (score 0):

You add background color of `ListView` in java file then it works correctly,

`listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);`